# How to execute a custom script on the Chrome's Dino offline game on current tab?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have made something like a mod for the Chrome offline T-rex game and I want to turn it into an extension so others can use for free
some of the features are more and bigger obstacles, timed game, multiple lifes, etc.

When playing the game, I can go to `Inspect element`, paste the script there and it would work. I tried to do a similar thing in the extension, but I couldn't.

I tried using the `chrome.tabs.executescript` function which worked for executing scripts on websites online, but when I go offline to play the game or open the `chrome://dino/` tab online, it doesn't execute the script on the page anymore.

How to make the extension work in all situations?

Comment: Extensions don't work on chrome:// URLs unless you explicitly start chrome with a command line switch, which is hardly what your users will do. If you still want it, look for examples on stack overflow.

Comment: improve title, fix spelling, formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As wOxxOm helpfully points out, `chrome://*` pages are off-limits to content script execution, even with the broadest `"<all_urls>"` permission.

So you will not be able to modify the actual `dino` page.

I presume the game itself is open-source and part of Chromium; your best bet is to just make a new version based off that code and publish it as a web app (or as a local extension page). Would be a good exercise to make it a [Progressive Web App](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/) as well, giving you offline capability (and more).